# "Ambiguous redirect" or ": : No such file or directory" trying to save while loop's output to file

Tags: bash

I have this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; 
do 
mkdir -p ./err_logs
mkdir -p ./out_logs
echo "starting main from bash";
>&2 echo "starting main from bash"
python3 main.py;
echo "done running main sleeping"; 
sleep 10;
echo "list of remaining python processes: ";
ps -ax | grep python;
echo "closing all of the remaining processes.";
ps ax | grep "python" | grep -v grep | awk '{print $1}' | xargs kill;
echo "done closing subprocesses";
err_path=$(realpath ./err_logs)
out_path=$(realpath ./out_logs)
err_log_path="${err_path}/err_$(date +"%d_%m").log"
out_log_path="${out_path}/out_$(date +"%d_%m").log"
echo "-------test---------" > $out_log_path 2> $err_log_path
done > $out_log_path 2> $err_log_path
```

Now the echo to file works just fine but for some reason I get `$out_log_path: ambiguous redirect` or `: : No such file or directory` if I use `done > "$out_log_path" 2> "$err_log_path"`

The only answer i found for it was checking if i have any space in the path but my path is: `/Users/user/tmp/test_bash/out_logs/out_02_05.log`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you change `>` to `>>` ? Other issues is there might  buffering issues with the long set of pipelines

Comment: At the moment you start the while loop, you need starting to send output to the files `$out_log_path` and `$err_log_path`, but these variables are not yet defined at that moment. So the last line (starting with `done`) will appear as `done 2>` to the shell, which probbly triggers the error message. Once the variables are defined, inside the loop, there are no problems and the `echo "-------test---------"` command sends its output to the correct files.

Comment: BTW, it would be better to use `pgrep` python than the `ps | grep | grep | awk`; but if you don't have pgrep, you can just use `ps | awk` -- `ps ax | awk '/python/ && ! /awk/ { print $1 }'` has `awk` doing all the work, no need for any `grep`s

Comment: (even better than that is to use a real process supervision system -- that way the PID of _your specific service_ can be identified, rather than targeting any/every Python process on the system; moreover, a good process supervisor will clean up stray subprocesses for you and restart your main program after exits, should you configure it to do so, so there's no need to write any of that logic yourself in the first place; also, using your OS's process supervision means that log management/alerting/etc tools will know what's going on).

Comment: This looks like you expect `python3 main.py` to only *start* the Python process, but that's not what it does. The command will only finish when the Python script exits. (It is of course possible that it, in turn, spawns background subprocesses which you need to wait for; but this would be unusual.)

Comment: Thanks for the help making the dirs outside the loop works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

mkdir -p ./err_logs
mkdir -p ./out_logs
err_path=$(realpath ./err_logs)
out_path=$(realpath ./out_logs)
err_log_path="${err_path}/err_$(date +"%d_%m").log"
out_log_path="${out_path}/out_$(date +"%d_%m").log"

while true; 
do 
  echo "starting main from bash"
  >&2 echo "starting main from bash"
  python3 main.py
  echo "done running main sleeping"
  sleep 10
  echo "list of remaining python processes: "
  ps -ax | grep python
  echo "closing all of the remaining processes."
  ps ax | grep "python" | grep -v grep | awk '{print $1}' | xargs kill;
  echo "done closing subprocesses"
  # echo "-------test---------" > $out_log_path 2> $err_log_path
done > $out_log_path 2> $err_log_path
```

Or, if the code has to run over several different days, this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

while true; 
do 
  mkdir -p ./err_logs
  mkdir -p ./out_logs
  err_path=$(realpath ./err_logs)
  out_path=$(realpath ./out_logs)
  err_log_path="${err_path}/err_$(date +"%d_%m").log"
  out_log_path="${out_path}/out_$(date +"%d_%m").log"
  echo "starting main from bash" >> $out_log_path 2>> $err_log_path
  >&2 echo "starting main from bash"
  python3 main.py   >> $out_log_path 2>> $err_log_path
  echo "done running main sleeping" >> $out_log_path 2>> $err_log_path
  sleep 10
  echo "list of remaining python processes: " >> $out_log_path 2>> $err_log_path
  ps -ax | grep python >> $out_log_path 2>> $err_log_path
  echo "closing all of the remaining processes." >> $out_log_path 2>> $err_log_path
  ps ax | grep "python" | grep -v grep | awk '{print $1}' | xargs kill >> $out_log_path 2>> $err_log_path
  echo "done closing subprocesses" >> $out_log_path 2>> $err_log_path
  echo "-------test---------" > $out_log_path 2>> $err_log_path
done
```

But this second option is not recommended.

Comment: Re: the `>&2 echo`, redirections work the same way at the front of the line as the end, so it's writing to the err_log.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: OK I will edit my code and remove my comment.

Comment: The second code sample is a lot less efficient than the OP's original code. Putting `>"$out_log_path" 2>"$err_log_path"` on the whole loop is preferred: it only opens the files _once_ instead of re-opening them for every write and closing them the moment that individual command is done (to be re-opened again later), and it also avoids needing to be careful to decide whether `>` or `>>` is appropriate for each case (you have a lot of `>`s that will blank the output file, thus clearing content written by the lines just above).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Oops, you are right regarding the `>` instead of `>>`. The second option is obviously not efficient, but I can't understand why the OP is computing the paths inside of the loop. Perhaps his code has to run over several days.

Comment: I'm not sure why running over several days would make a difference here. Is the worry about writes being buffered in memory instead of written immediately? Because each individual program has to flush its own buffers before it exits, and `echo` performs writes immediately, I don't think there's any risk of that here... at least, not any additional risk; if the Python program buffers its writes and each individual run happens over a long period of time, it's the same amount of problem either way (buffering potentially happens until that individual Python run exits in both cases).